# What is the difference between widget object and widget instance?

Tags: widgets

I am new to wordpress and following a tutorial to create a new widget.
I have noticed in some situations **$instance** variable is used and some situations **$this** is used. Like

```
$instance['title']

$this->get_field_id( 'title' )
```

I know first line returns the title value and second line returns the id of the field. But ins't **$this** means the instantiated object of the class?
Why do I have to use **$instance** variable too? 
Can't we use **$this** to get title **value** of widget?

Answer (score 0):

The [WP_Widget](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget/) class can be a bit confusing as an object instance of it (a child class must be used) doesn't represent a specific instance of a widget. It is more of an object to handle all instances of this widget class.

`$instance` is a variable repeatedly used within the WP_Widget class (and hence also in all child classes). It doesn't actually hold a reference to an instance of a php Object. Instead it is just an array with settings for an incarnation of a WordPress widget. This array() gets saved to the DB and retrieved again to be able to save the settings for the different widgets.

`$this` is a pseudo-variable which references the current instantiation of the widget class. So this is actually a reference to a php object instance, but it is not for a specific widget instance.